# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. What am I not doing right

Tags: python, mysql

I have tried:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO "+ tablenane + " ("+ ",".join(headers) +") VALUES (" + ",".join(["%s"] * len(headers)) + ")"
```

and:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO "+ tablenane + " ("+ ",".join(headers) +") VALUES (" + ",".join(["?"] * len(headers)) + ")"
```

but still get the same error when I run `cursor.executemany(sql, dataset)`

`dataset = [(a,b,c),(d,e,f)]` - A list of tuples

Both columns and values are dynamic, because there 40 columns.
All table columns are of type VARCHAR and I ensure the data is converted to string before insertion

Using python 2.7 and mysql

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that MySQL-python does not allow "?".
All I was missing was the db.commit()

Final query was

sql = "INSERT INTO "+ tablenane + " ("+ ",".join(headers) +") VALUES (" + ",".join(['%s'] * len(headers)) + ")"

cursor.executemany(sql, dataset)

db.commit(). Though not sure why insertion needs a commit yet creation does not.

Thanks